# Se me pierde las variables de Session en asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Después de haber iniciado session, de forma repentina se borran todas las variables de session.
Por ejemplo yo accedo asi:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(MembersViewModels user)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Isvalid(user.email, user.password))
            {
                Session["usuario"] = "nombre_usuario";
                Session["tipo_usuario"] = "administrador";
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.email, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuario");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["MensajeErrorAcceso"] = "Error: su email o contraseña es incorrecta";
                //ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

estas variables  Session["usuario"], Session["tipo_usuario"] se me borran.

existe alguna manera de mantener la variable de session, o evitar que se pierda o por lo menos darle mas tiempo al usuario.

He probado con esto en la webconfig del proyecto:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="20" />
```

pero me añade a la url un codigo encriptado que me impide acceder, a pesar que estoy con las credenciales correcta.

[image: en la url, me añade una secuencia de caracteres]

En todo caso, en MVC, tiene dos webconfing, uno el que está en la vista, y otro en el proyecto. Si tuviera que modificar algo en la webconfig, cual sería?

Comment: Hola @Danilo , el web.config de la carpeta de las vistas se utiliza generalemente para agregar de forma global espacios de nombres a tus vistas en razor, asi que las configuraciones generales de la aplicación tales como la sesión se realizan en **el web.config en la raiz de tu proyecto**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que pueden causar que la sesión desaparezca misteriosamente.

1. El tiempo de espera de la sesión ha expirado. SessionTimeout
2. Que hayas actualizado tu web.config u otro tipo de archivo que hace que tu AppDomain(el dominio de aplicación) se recicle.
3. El AppPool en IIS se haya reciclado.
4. Que hayas actualizado tu sitio con una gran cantidad de archivos, y ASP.NET haya destruido de forma proactiva el AppDomain para volver a compilar y preservar la memoria.

Para configurar el tiempo de expiracion de la sesion, puedes utlizar el web.config. Recuerda que la expiracion se especifica en minutos.

```
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="80" />
</system.web>
```

Si está utilizando IIS 7 o 7,5, aquí hay algunas cosas que puedes buscar:

- De forma predeterminada, IIS establece que se haga apaguen los AppPools después de un período de inactividad.
- De forma predeterminada, IIS establece que los AppPools se reciclen cada 1740 minutos (obviamente dependiendo de la configuración de la raíz, sino se toma el valor por defecto).
- En IIS, echa un vistazo a los "Configuración avanzada" de su AppPool. Ahi hay una propiedad llamada "Tiempo de espera inactivo" o **Idle Time-out**. Establece el valor en cero o a un número mayor que el valor predeterminado(20).
  [image: idle-timeout]
- En IIS, compruebe los ajustes de "reciclaje" del AppPool. Aquí puedes activar o desactivar que el AppPool se recicle. 
  [image: Recycling]

Si está actualizando los archivos en tu aplicación web,debes estar consciente de que todas las sesiones se perderán. Sin embargo, es posible que no tengas en cuenta que esto puede suceder varias veces. Si actualizas 15 o más archivos (aspx, dll, etc), hay una gran probabilidad de que tengas varios reinicios durante un período de tiempo, dado que estas páginas se vuelven a compilar a medida que los usuarios acceden al sitio. 
Referencia 
* http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319947
* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.numrecompilesbeforeapprestart.aspx

En ese caso, deberas ajutar el numero de compilaiones antes de un reinicio (**numCompilesBeforeAppRestart**) a un número más alto (o reiniciar manualmente el AppPool).

Adicionalmente, puedes manejar los eventos **Application_SessionStart** y **Application_SessionEnd** para ser notificados cuando se crea o se puso fin a una sesión.

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application_started");  //write console
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session_End"); //write console
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session_Start"); //write console
        }

        protected void Application_End()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application_ended"); //write console
        }
```

Por otro ladod,la clase **HttpSessionState** también tiene una propiedad **IsNewSession** que se puede comprobar en cualquier solicitud(**request**) para determinar si se ha creado una nueva sesión para el usuario activo.

```
public ActionResult OtraAccion()
{

    if (Session.IsNewSession)
    {                    
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); //just in case not done yet
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectoToAction("Timeout");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

> Por último, si es posible en tu escenario, utiliza un modo de sesión
>   externa(Out of proc) como SQL Server o un servidor de estado( State
>   Server).
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754032%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Hola @Jesus Angulo, esa configuracion:

<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="80" />
</system.web>

en cual webconfig debería colocarse, ya que en MVC, existe dos webconfig, una que está en la vista y la otra en el proyecto

Comment: Hola Danilo, en el proyecto

Comment: regresó el buen @JesusAngulo a SOes! bienvenido de vuelta hermano :D

Comment: hahahha hola @fredyfx gracias :) , aqui a apoyar en lo que se puede.

Comment: de nada, siempre vamos #ConTodoElPower2.0! :D

Comment: excelente, muy buena explicación @Jesus Angulo ...dentro de todo el analisis que hacia mientras miraba tu codigo, había uno que me llamaba la atención:

public ActionResult OtraAccion()
{

    if (Session.IsNewSession)
    {                    
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); //just in case not done yet
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectoToAction("Timeout");
    }
    return View(user);
}

que pasa si no es un ActionResult , sino un JsonResult, como se retornaría la redireccion, RedirectoToAction("Timeout");

Comment: En ese caso aun tienes la opción de hacer la dirección en el objeto Response usando **Response.Redirect("url/destino", true);**